# Jquery: Push FormData?

Tags: javascript, jquery, form-data

Is there a way to add additional data to a formdata element that handles a file upload?  I know formdata doesn't support .push()?

```
$("frm").submit(function (e) {
 e.preventDefault();
 var data = new FormData($(this)[0]);

 });
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, you want to add extra keys and values to the FormData object after taking them from the form. If so, yes you can! It uses the `append` method:

```
data.append('SomeField', 'SomeValue');
```

You can do this with a string, or with a `Blob` or `File` object as suits you.

This is documented in the [MDN page for `FormData`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData#append%28%29).

Comment: Thanks for that advice, that works perfectly.  I'm more familiar with using .serializeArray() and pushing new values into it.  This is exactly what I needed to know.